# How to remove selected items from a listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selecteditem, visual-studio-2015

This is for a VB.NET 4.5 project in VS2015 Community.

I am trying to remove certain selected items from a listbox, but only if the selected item meets a condition. I've found plenty of examples on how to remove selected items. But nothing that works with a condition nested in the loop going through the selected items (at least, I can't get the examples to work with what I'm trying to do...)

Here's my code:

```
    Dim somecondition As Boolean = True
    Dim folder As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstBoxFoldersBackingUp.SelectedItems.Count - 1

        If somecondition = True Then
            folder = lstBoxFoldersBackingUp.SelectedItems.Item(i)
            Console.WriteLine("folder: " & folder)
            lstBoxFoldersBackingUp.SelectedItems.Remove(lstBoxFoldersBackingUp.SelectedItems.Item(i))
        End If
    Next
```

The console output correctly shows the text for the current iteration's item, but I can't get the Remove() to work. As the code is now, I get the console output, but the listbox doesn't change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing items changes the index position of the items.  Lots of ways around this, but from your code, try iterating backwards to avoid that problem.  You should also remove the item from the Items collection, not the SelectedItems collection:

```
For i As Integer = lstBoxFoldersBackingUp.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If somecondition = True Then
    folder = lstBoxFoldersBackingUp.SelectedItems.Item(i)
    Console.WriteLine("folder: " & folder)              
    lstBoxFoldersBackingUp.Items.Remove(lstBoxFoldersBackingUp.SelectedItems(i))
  End If
Next
```

Comment: why the thumbs down it seemed like a valid question - with code?

Comment: @codeMonger123 I didn't downvote — I tried to help.  :-)

Comment: That works, but **how**? With the just the second item in the listbox selected, when I get to the Remove() line, the value of `i` is 0 because it's the only item in the selecteditems collection. So we're passing the Remove() method the value of 0, which, I would think, would be the first item in the listbox's Items collection...

Comment: @marky Items and SelectedItems are two different collections.  SelectedItems(i) is refering to a specific item in the Items(i) collection.  The code is using Remove, not RemoveAt, which would need the proper index.

Comment: I didnt think that you did.

Comment: @LarsTech Subtle, but I understand the distinction. Thanks for the code and the explanation!

Comment: @codeMonger123 Then your comment belonged to the question, not to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this in order to remove a selected item from the listbox
  ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi Robert.  Great answer, but just a little formatitng tip: If you use a single quote (above the tilde, next to the 1 on most ANSI keyboards), it'll format as a code snippet.  Like this: `ListBox1.Items`

Answer (score 0):

This will not work:

```
ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

You need to define exactly which items will be deleted, so the next works fine for me:

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
```

However it removes one line every time it is called.